# How can I use a specific font in a program listing in Lyx?

Tags: fonts, listings, lyx

I would like to know how to use a specific font (Arial, for example) in a program listing.

The idea is to insert in my document a part of code in a 'program listing'. I found a way to insert some parameters like the frame and the language code but I was not able to change the font.

Comment: A minimum working example will help. For example, is XeTeX an option, or only plain latex? The answer depends on the options.

Answer (score 4):

As long as using XeTeX or LuaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX is an option, you can use basically whichever font you have installed in your system.

1. Document --> Settings --> Fonts. Check the box for *Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)* at the top:

   [image]
2. Move down to the LaTeX preamble panel, add

   ```
   \newfontfamily\mylistingsfont{<name of font>}
   ```

   [image]
3. If you want the setting to be global, for all listings, move up to the Listings-panel (still in the Document settings), add

   ```
   basicstyle=\mylistingsfont
   ```

   to the options.

   [image]